# is $x^{1000,000,000}$ a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial)

> A polynomial equation, also called algebraic equation, is an equation
>   of the form
>
> $a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dotsb +a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x+a_{0}$

and

> a polynomial can either be zero or can be written as the sum of a
>   finite number of non-zero terms

so, as long as the n is a finite number, such as 2 billion, 3 trillion,

$P = x^n$

is a polynomial equation, do I understand this right?

Comment: “Polynomial” or “Polynomial equation”?

Comment: yes that's right. THe only thing I'd say is the term "expression" is better than "equation" in this context, because there are no $=$ signs anywhere

Comment: That is not an equation. Even wiki has the equal sign there.

Comment: Why did you omit Wikipedia's $=0$ from the statement of the equation?

Comment: The important thing is not how large the exponent is (it doesn't matter if its 2, 3, or a billion). The important thing is to understand what the words 'equation' and 'polynomial' mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A polynomial *equation* is of the form

$$a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dotsb +a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x+a_{0} \color{red}{ \boldsymbol{=0}}$$

while what you wrote is just the general form of a *polynomial*.

And indeed, if you check the definition and plug in $n=100000000000$ with $a_n=1$ and $a_k=0$ for all $k \neq n$ then we see that $x^{100000000000}$ is a polynomial. (But by itself not a polynomial *equation*.)

Comment: ...and $x^{100000000}=0$ *is* a polynomial equation.